# Можно ли вызвать код python из Java на Android?

Tags: java, android, python, android-studio

Есть ли какие-либо способы заставить работать скрипт на python вместе с кодом Java на Android. Если да то какие? Интересует именно связка python и java. Библиотеки вроде kivy и прочие для разработки на python под Android только от безысходности.

Если способы все-таки есть, подскажите как грамотно связать код в Android Studio, если это имеет значение.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097491/call-and-receive-output-from-python-script-in-java  - поищите здесь

Answer (score 1):

Тут есть два пути решения проблемы.

Первый, это использвоание библиотеки java, умеющей выполнять код питона. Самый известный пример это [Jython](https://www.jython.org/index). Но у такого подхода есть свои минусы. Например вы не сможете устанавливать библиотеки, частично написанные на C, и будет страдать скорость программ.

Второй, не побоюсь сказать более правильный, вариант - это связать Java и Python приложение через локальный сервер. Легче всего это сделать по REST API - обмен будет проводиться через JSON объекты. Очень быстро и удобно подобные сервера создаются на [Flask-RESTful](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#a-minimal-api).

Создаете на локальном хосте (который почти всегда 127.0.0.1) и выбранном свободном порте RESTful сервер, который по обращению к нужной ссылке принимает JSON с нужными данными и отдает JSON с результатом

Со стороны Java надо сформировать JSON, отправить его по адресу `https://<локальный хост>:<порт>/<путь>`, получить JSON с ответом сервера и взять оттуда результат. <путь> определяется на сервере и может быть любым. Более того по разным путям вы можете иметь разные сервисы, в то время как сервер поддерживающий их будет один.

И вот, в два шага, связка Java с Python (или с чем угодно еще) через сервер готова.